# NSView bounds not changing after setting new origin

Tags: macos, cocoa, positioning, nsview, zooming

I have a custom NSView which shrinks or enlarges an image on a magnification event. However, I noticed that even after setting the new bounds size and origin, only the size seem to have an effect on what is being displayed:

[image]

The bounds origin seems to be sticking to the lower left corner (0, 0) when I do not want it to. I update the bounds size and origin be overriding -(void)magnifyWithEvent:

```
-(void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {

    CGFloat zoomFactor = [event magnification] + 1.0;

    CGSize newSize = [self bounds].size;

    newSize.width = newSize.width * zoomFactor;
    newSize.height = newSize.height * zoomFactor;

    [self setBoundsSize:newSize];

    CGSize viewFrameSize = [self frame].size;
    CGPoint newOrigin;
    newOrigin.x = (viewFrameSize.width - newSize.width) / 2.0;
    newOrigin.y = (viewFrameSize.height - newSize.height) / 2.0;

    [self setBoundsOrigin:newOrigin];

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}
```

The printout from the console log shows that the bounds origin is changing:

```
2014-10-12 09:50:00.315 ZoomImageViewer[8047:303] Bounds origin x: 105.317268 y: 78.987951
2014-10-12 09:50:00.316 ZoomImageViewer[8047:303] Frame origin x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000
2014-10-12 09:50:00.333 ZoomImageViewer[8047:303] Bounds origin x: 106.124921 y: 79.593691
2014-10-12 09:50:00.333 ZoomImageViewer[8047:303] Frame origin x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000
2014-10-12 09:50:00.347 ZoomImageViewer[8047:303] Bounds origin x: 106.927730 y: 80.195798
2014-10-12 09:50:00.347 ZoomImageViewer[8047:303] Frame origin x: 0.000000 y: 0.000000
```

Is there a way to get the bounds to be centered as I want it or am I misunderstanding how this should work?

Comment: Show the view's `-drawRect:` implementation any any relevant helper methods. You may have the bounds right but be effectively counteracting the change by how you draw.

Comment: @KenThomases, I found a solution problem. Since I enabled layer-backing for the custom NSView, I needed to change the origin of the root layer object, then change the bounds size for the view and root layer object. Fixed it...